# Compiler dropping my type conversion?

Tags: java, static-typing

I'm puzzled by what I had to do to get this code to work. It seems as if the compiler optimized away a type conversion that I needed, or there's something else I don't understand here.

I have various objects that are stored in the database that implement the interface `Foo`. I have an object, `bar`, which holds data I'm using to retrieve my `Foo` objects. `bar` has these methods:

```
Class getFooClass()

Long getFooId()
```

I pass the class and ID to a method with this signature, which delegates to hibernate which retrieves the subject based on its class and ID:

```
public <T> T get(Class<T> clazz, Serializable id);
```

There are different implementers of `Foo`, and some of these hibernate objects have a `Long` id, and others have an `Integer` id. Although this method accepts either, farther down it had better have the right one. So when I tried to call `get()` on an object with an `Integer` id, as follows, I understandably got an error complaining that I had provided a `Long` where an `Integer` was required:

```
    get(bar.getFooClass(), bar.getFooId());
```

There's no hibernate problem here, I just need to provide an `Integer` where an `Integer` id is required and a `Long` where a `Long` id is required. So I added a method to `bar`, `hasLongId()`, and tried this: (at this point you may be thinking this isn't a good design, but that's not my question right now)

```
get(bar.getFooClass(),
    bar.hasLongId() ? bar.getFooId() : bar.getFooId().intValue());
```

And it still complained that I had provided a `Long`. That seemed strange. Then I tried this:

```
get(bar.getFooClass(),
    bar.hasLongId() ? bar.getFooId() 
                    : new Integer(bar.getFooId().intValue()));
```

Same error! How can this be? So I stepped through in the debugger, and yes, it stepped through `intValue()` and also through the `Integer` constructor, but then in the get method, the passed parameter was in fact a `Long`—the same `Long` object that was returned from `getFooId()`.

I don't understand what's happening, so I just try various things:

```
Integer intId = bar.getFooId().intValue();
get(bar.getFooClass(), bar.hasLongId() ? bar.getFooId() : intId);   
// same error
```

and

```
Serializable id = bar.hasLongId() ? bar.getFooId() 
                                : new Integer(bar.getFooId().intValue());
get(bar.getFooClass(), id); 
// same error
```

And finally:

```
Serializable id;
if (bar.hasLongId()) {
    id = bar.getFooId();
} else {
    id = bar.getFooId().intValue();
}
get(bar.getFooClass(), id);
```

This one works. So apparently it has something to do with the ternary operator. But why? Can someone explain what happened here?

Comment: There's not enough information. Don't paraphrase the code and don't summarize the error messages. I might or might not be able to figure out what's wrong based on what you gave us, but I'm not going to spend much time on it because I can tell that you haven't given us anything complete.

Comment: Not related to your question, but why don't you make `getFooId()` return a `Number` instead of the extra method and type conversion?

Comment: Voting to reopen because the other question doesn't discuss ternary expressions or boxed values.

Comment: Agree on @shmosel, the originally marked-as-duplicated question is different.  So I reopened this question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a great question and goes into the nitty gritty details of the semantics of the ternary expression. No, your compiler is not broken or playing tricks on you.

In this case, if the types of the second and third operands of the ternary expression is `long` and `int`, then the resulting type is always `long`. This is due to [*binary numeric promotion*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).

According to the [JLS (Java Language Specification)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> ..., binary numeric promotion is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands.

The values are getting unboxed due to rule #1 of *Binary Numeric Promotion*:

> If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion

What this means essentially, that when you have a ternary expression, the resulting type of the expression must be determinable statically (at compile time). The second and third operands must be coerced into a single type, which is the type of the expression. If both operands are a numeric type, binary numeric promotion kicks in to determine the final type of the expression.

Comment: What about the explicitly boxed type? Is it getting unboxed? Why?

Comment: Good answer.  It will be more complete, as @shmosel mentioned, to tell why the compiler, when encounter ternary operator with `condition ? Long : int ` or `condition? Long : Integer`, is deciding to auto-unbox the `Long` to form `condition ? long : int`. The form `condition? Long : Integer` should also be valid here?

Comment: Edited to answer the questions above.